# How can i get http response code more quickly in java than getResponseCode?

Tags: java, http-headers, http-status-codes

I want to get http response code of over 10000000 web sites. So, I used Http(s)?URLConnection class in java.

Code is

```
HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection)address.openConnection();
http.setReadTimeout(300000);
return http.getResponseCode();
```

But I think that it is very slow. When I calculate total time, it is over 10days.

Do you know more fast function or other ways to get HTTP response code in Java?

Comment: The fact is that in order to get 10M response codes, you will have to send 10M requests, which will take a very long time to return from. I'm not surprised it's at least 10 days; I would think it would be far longer than that.

Comment: @Anon: Maybe he's writing a web-crawler.

Comment: I don't know why i do that. my boss oder that to me.

Comment: @Mastojun: And you're not interested enough to ask why? You're (presumably) an intelligent person, not a code-writing automaton. Identify what problem this is intended to solve, and think about other ways of solving it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use multiple threads; a pool of 1000 threads will drop your elapsed time by a factor of 1000.
2. Use non-blocking I/O.  Running 1000 concurrent connections will drop your total time by a factor of 1000.

Comment: Why will a pool of 1000 threads drop the elapsed time only by a factor of 100?

Comment: I would also recommend reading up on web crawlers. There are a lot of other considerations besides sheer performance. For instance, flooding web sites with requests can get your IP address blocked, so crawlers have to incorporate smarts to not issue too many requests to the same hosts. Beyond that it is just a matter of breaking up the problem into smaller batches and running those batches in parallel, on many threads as this answer suggests and ultimately on many machines.

Comment: And fire a HEAD request instead of a GET request. You're required to consume the HTTP response body otherwise the HTTP connection won't be immediately available for reuse. A HEAD request doesn't include the body. The total time will drop more.